# Why can't I declare a position in my multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to do a 3d version of an L-Syste. But I cannot declare elements in my multidimensional array. When I debug, I see that the element stays the same.
I call for example arraygrowth [0][1] = 100;
But the Element at that position stays 0

```
let arraygrowth =[];
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)); 
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

arraygrowth [0][1] = 100;
arraygrowth [1][1] = 100;
arraygrowth [2][1] = 100;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "declare my position". `j` is your position within `w` (might be a good idea to use more descriptive variable names). If you want to keep track of some position within `arraygrowth`, declare a new variable for that purpose...

Comment: I know. Im calling the function with grow(arraygrowth, word). But the declaration still does not happen in my else if statement. When I call arraygrowth [0][1] = 100;
        arraygrowth [1][1] = 100;
        arraygrowth [2][1] = 100; The array at this positions still stays 0, when it should be 100

Comment: You should simplify your example to the essence of the problem. All the `word` string replacement is irrelevant and misleading when the issue stems from `araygrowth[0][1] = 100;` Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok thank you for your comment. My bad. I Edited it know

Comment: @BurakErtan `arraygrowth` is modified exactly how you tell it to be modified; you set the second element to `100` for each entry in `arraygrowth`. Assuming this is how you modify a `THREE.Vector3` at all--it seems like `setY` would make more sense since AFAIK they're not arrays.

Comment: How are you determining that the value is not changing? I suggest using `console.log(JSON.stringify(arraygrowth, null, 2))` after each attempt and show the output.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok thank you, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up your code, you're essentially doing this:

```js
let arraygrowth =[];
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)); 
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
arraygrowth.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

arraygrowth [0][1] = 100;
arraygrowth [1][1] = 100;
arraygrowth [2][1] = 100;
```

This is the equivalent of `new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)[1] = 100;` ... which doesn't make sense. That this is not how you change the `x, y, z` parameters of a Vector3. When you call `arraygrowth[0]`, you get a `Vector3`, and now you have to use one of its properties or methods to assign the value you want. For example:

```js
arraygrowth[0].y = 100; // Sets y value
arraygrowth[0].setY(100); // Also sets y value
arraygrowth[0].setComponent(1) = 100; // Also sets y value
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.setComponent